# PHP strtotime Function: first day of this year

Tags: php, strtotime

I am testing some code using PHP’s `strtotime()` function, but I can’t work out how PHP is interpreting the following:

```
strtotime('first day of this year')
```

I get `Tue Sep 01 2015` (currently it is Sunday 27 September in Australia).

Is this some strange new usage of “year” that I was previously unaware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mention the month (and you don't), `strtotime` is built to assume you mean the *current* month. The same goes with year, btw; that's why it's enough to build your expression as simple as...

```
strtotime('first day of January');
```

, as `this year` will be used if skipped in definition anyway.

Note the difference with...

```
strtotime('first day of first month');
```

This will give you October, 1 (in September), as it's the first day of the first month *since* current.

Comment: I think I see it. From what you say it is being interpreted as `first day [of this month]  of this year`. Thanks. Sorry I didn’t respond to this answer long before.